# Is it safe to unlink and recreate a SQLite db that was opened in read-only mode?

Tags: sqlite

I have a use case like this:

- I have a cluster of server applications, each on their machine
- they each query a SQLite DB file on a local filesystem via JDBC
- the DB is opened in read-only mode (so, e.g. no WAL journal files are created)
- periodically, this DB file is regenerated by a batch process and synced to the machines running the server application

The server is using SQLite as a glorified key-value store, basically - very simple queries, only reads, no writes.

This appears to work, in that the new data is visible to the server application.

However, is this safe?

https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#unlink notes

> unlinking or renaming an open database file results in behavior that is undefined and probably undesirable.

But that seems to be in the context of a read-write database, due to the additional files needed for WAL logs.

It seems like SQLite does take some steps to detect when the file is changed beneath it - eg section 5.11 of https://www.sqlite.org/fileio.html talks about invalidating the in-memory page cache when SQLite detects that the file has been changed beneath it.

For now, I'm erring on the side of caution and closing/re-opening the file, but for my particular use case, there'd be less code to maintain if I could just stomp on the file via unlink+rename and delegate to SQLite itself to detect and handle this scenario.

Comment: An open file must not be changed.